# URL Encoding Error trying to access Infopath Form from mobile device

Tags: 2013, infopath, mobile

While trying out the default mobile view in my SharePoint 2013 site, I navigate to an Infopath Document Library, and then click on one of the elements, I get a URL in which SharePoint seems to not be able to decode the URL correctly (Originally it sent me an error that was solved by activating the Session State Service, but now there is this other, more cryptic and frustrating error).

The URL in the list looks like this (domain names removed and guids randomly changed):

> https://|url|/|ListName|/NAME%20OF%20THE%20DOCUMENT.xml?Mobile=1&Source=%2F%5Flayouts%2F15%2Fmobile%2Fviewa%2Easpx%3FList%3De1234598%252Dcd86%252D4d34%252D9d1b%252Da1a855240d19%26View%3D9d12345c%252D68e3%252D4811%252D89ee%252Dc7cfd858d7a9

Then, it is redirected here:

> https://|url|/_layouts/15/Mobile/MobileFormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/|ListName|/NAME%20OF%20THE%20LIST.xml&Source=%252f%255flayouts%252f15%252fmobile%252fviewa%252easpx%253flist%253de1234598%25252dcd86%25252d4d34%25252d9d1b%25252da1a855240d19%2526view%253d9d89f07c%2525123453%25252d4811%25252d89ee%25252dc7cfd858d7a9&OpenIn=PreferClient&mobile=1

Which, in turn, gives me this error message in Spanish:

> La dirección URL %2f%5flayouts%2f15%2fmobile%2fviewa%2easpx%3flist%3de1112345%252dcd86%252d4d34%252d9d1b%252da1a855240d19%26view%3d9d12345c%252d68e3%252d4811%252d89ee%252dc7cfd858d7a9 es una dirección URL relativa no admitida. Para solucionar este problema, use una dirección URL relativa del sitio que comience con '~site' o una dirección URL relativa de la colección de sitios que comience con '~sitecollection'.

Which says the the direction is not an admitted relative URL, to solve that problem, use a relative site URL that starts with `~site` or `~sitecollection`

So, appearently SharePoint epic fails to decode its own URL, and I'm stuck. Do you have any workaround for this?